# Printing two string literals with same value gives same address

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, cpu-architecture

Can someone explain the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void some_fn(char *x)
{
    printf("%d\n", x);
}

int main()
{
    // They are stored on the same memory address
    some_fn("A");
    some_fn("A");

    some_fn("B");
}
```

Why would:

```
    some_fn("A");
    some_fn("A");
```

print be stored on the same memory address?

Comment: because `"A"` is a string literal, which most likely goes into a read-only portion of the program, and the compiler is smart enough to realize `"A"` and `"A"` are the same string, so it only stores it once and uses that address any time it's referenced. Also, print out pointers with `printf("%p"...)`

Comment: A better question is why *shouldn't* they be stored in the same address?

Comment: And you're *not* passing any `char`s to your function.  You're passing  pointers to `char`, just as it requires.  Those pointers are the result of the decay of string literals, which are arrays of `char`, to pointers, just as occurs whenever any array value appears as a function argument.

Comment: If you did `char str[] = "A";`, that would force the compiler to create a modifiable copy of the string-literal initializer.  (It could still optimize it away since it can inline `some_fn` and see that you're not doing anything that needs a separate copy).  `const char str[] = "A";` is likely to not result in any wasted copying.

Comment: @Barmar that I did actually think, I initially thought that: since the string literal can't be changed, then the compiler would think that they are the same thing and use the existing one instead of allocating more memory, but then I thought that I'd better not guess and ask someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, off using `%d` to print a pointer (as you had in your code originally before you edited it) is invalid and results in undefined behavior.  You should use the `%p` pointer instead.

That being said, the two calls to `some_fn` are both being passed a string literal, each of which happens to be the same.  String literals are typically stored in a read-only section of memory, and when a particular string literal appears in the code multiple times, the compiler will typically use a single instance of that literal.  So in that case the address of that literal is the same when it appears in different places.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I've edited my original post indeed.
This is what I initially thought as well, that the compiler wouldn't waste memory noticing two of the same String literals.

Comment: @dud3 Please don't edit question with the corrections provided in the answers. This makes the entire post seem confusing.

Comment: @2501 Roger that, sorry my bad.